# Incoherencia de tipo y metodo

Tags: c#

Buenas tardes llevo varios dias con este problema y no puedo resolverlo, este es mi codigo, me marca que el apartado

public UserController es menos accesible que el metodo IUserService le agradeceria si alguien pudiera ayudarme

```
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    private IUserService _userService;

    public ***UserController***(IUserService userService) 
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y como esta definido IUserService?

Answer (score 4):

El constructor de `UserController` es público (`public`) pero recibe un parámetro de tipo `IUserService` que es privado (`private`), posiblemente sea una clase anidada.

Dado que privado (`private`) es menos accesible que público (`public`) el compilador se queja; para solucionarlo `IUserService` debe ser igual o más accesible que `UserController`.